# bridge on openVPN client

Tags: openvpn, bridge, tun

I have some problem with setting up what i call  a "remote entry point" (i'm sure ther is a real name for this)
First things First : Here is my setup :

```
||=============================================================||
||                                                             ||
||                            |----------------------|         ||
||  |------------------|      |SERVER :              |         ||
||  |PC1 : 192.168.0.42|      |   eth0 : 12.34.56.78 |         ||
||  | tun0 : 10.8.0.6  |      |   tun0 : 10.8.0.1/16 |         ||
||  |------------------|      |----------------------|         ||
||           |                          |                      ||
||           |                          |                      ||
||  |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|           |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|              ||
||  | 192.168.0.0/24 |-----------| THE INTERNET |              ||
||  |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|           |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|              ||
||                                      |                      ||
||                                      |                      ||
||     |-------------------|     |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|             ||
||     |PC2 : 10.34.16.222 |-----| 10.34.16.0/16 |             ||
||     |-------------------|     |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|             ||
||                                      |                      ||
||                                      |                      ||
||                           |----------------------|          ||
||                           |SERVER "Client" :     |          ||
||                           |   wlan0 : 10.34.56.78|          ||
||                           |   tun0 : 10.8.0.10   |          ||
||                           |----------------------|          ||
||=============================================================||
```

- I want to connect from PC1 to PC2 across the network.
- PC1 and SERVER "Client" are connected to the OpenVPN SERVER as client.

I've set up all openvpn and i can successfully pin the client server from pc1.
Nevertheless, i can't ping PC2 from PC1. I think i must create a bridge between wlan0 and tun0  but i don't have any idea how to do that !

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN can be set up as a "router" so clients can communicate with each other. Uncomment `client-to-client` in your server.conf file, then restart the service and the tunnels.

Comment: I've already done that, my problem is realy at the "client" server where packet are not routed from the tun interface to the physical interface